# run GUI application on startup after network is up

Tags: startup, gui, lxde, lubuntu

I need to automatically start a GUI application at startup, but after network is up, what is the right way to do it?
My OS is Lubuntu with LXDE.
I tried different ways, such as crontab, rc.local and autostart with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how you can place a startup script for LXDE (see [the documentation](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart)), you can always build a custom script:

```
until ip link show $interface | grep -F -q "state UP"; do
    sleep 10 # wait every ten second
done
# interface is up, now start program
exec bla
```

*Explanation:*

- `ip link show $interface` prints a line with the status of the interface (in this case `enp0s25`):

  > 3: enp0s25:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
- `grep -F -q "state UP"` checks if the output contains the line `state UP`. If yes, it returns success (exit code 0), otherwise failure (exit code 1).
- `until … do; sleep 10; done` executes `sleep 10` until the command was successful, i.e. until `ip` shows `state UP`. As long as the interface is not up, wait 10 second and check again.
- when the interface is up, the loop finishes and the following script is executed.

This is of course "busy waiting" and not an ideal solution, but will always work. (Or, use `ping -W 2 -c 1 google.com >& /dev/null` instead of `ip … | grep` if you want to ensure real internet connectivity.)

If you use some network manager, check its documentation if you can add scripts that are executed when it established a network connection.
However, this may only work with root access, which complicates starting a program within your X session.